# Is there any downside to using .row within bootstrap forms?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand that bootstrap `.form-horizontal` is the standard, and causes `.form-group` to behave like a row.
This means that `<div class="row">` is not needed, but what is the downside to building my layout like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
              <!--Content-->
         </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
              <!--Content-->
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <!--More Content-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case (without a `.form-xx` modifier class as an ancestor), `.form-group` does nothing but add space at the bottom. From BS's CSS:

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You can simply add that class to the row instead to achieve the same result, like:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <!--Content-->
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <!--Content-->
     </div>
</div>
```